# Concatenate textfield names

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want a price field to be displayed as `'$'+ 'PRICE'` but nothing shows when I use the included code. Can someone please tell me how to concatenate so that the view displays price as `$123('PRICE')`?

```
{
    xtype    : 'textfield',
    label    : 'Price',
    name     : 'PRICE'(this comes from store data),
    readOnly : true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for the textfield to have a read only value of $XXX, $XXX('PRICE') and 'PRICE'(XXXX) all in the same question. However I think your mistake is just that you are using the `name` config instead of `value`. Give the following a shot an see if you can make that work.

```
        {    
            xtype    : 'textfield',
            label    : 'Price',
            value     : '$' + 'Price',
            readOnly : true
        }
```

If it turns out that you are instead having trouble getting the actual numeric value for price into the field that is a different issue just post the code involved with loading that data and I'll do my best to help.

Good luck, Brad

Comment: Firstly Thank you for your help..but if I give value instead of name ..it is not printing the data(like if the price value in the store data is 123) ..it is just showing $PRICE.. so I want to concatenate $ and 'PRICE'.. PRICE value comes from the store so I am using 'name' to display it as value of a label..

Comment: Can you try adding a copy of the price field in your model using the convert function named something like displayPrice that simply returns '$ + price'? Then in the text field reference displayPrice instead of price. If you need an example lookup Ext.data.Field convert. Let me know if you need an example and I'll post one when I'm not on a phone.